# Angular2 Url Encoded JSON Matrix Parameters

Tags: javascript, json, angular, urlencode, url-encoding

I am having an issue with Angular2 handling url encoded JSON matrix parameters. I needed to create a custom UrlSerializer in order to handle parenthesis inside string fields within the JSON.  For example: user agent strings. The custom serializer looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    constructor(
        private defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer
    ) {}
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {

        const defaultTree = this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url);
        return defaultTree;
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
        // Use the default serializer to create a url.
        const defaultSerialization = this.defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree);
        const parenthesisFix = defaultSerialization
            .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
            .replace(/\)/g, '%29');
        return parenthesisFix;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the parenthesis are being serialized in addition to the standard serialization, which by default assumes parenthesis are special characters.
The code works correctly for simple values.  Here, two matrix params ('comp_id' and 'camp_id') are parsed into a URL Tree.

[image]

Inspecting the root.children.primary.segments["0"].parameters path of the tree yields the object that we expect to see deserialized:

[image]

And the router params subscription observes those parameters as expected:

[image]

**However**, in the case where a matrix parameter ('r' in this example) is a url encoded JSON string we have:

[image]

Again, in the root.children.primary.segments["0"].parameters path of the tree, we can see the object we would expect populated (**Note:** the parenthesis are properly deserialized and the string is valid JSON at this point, not that it should matter since this is simply a string field):

[image]

Except this time, the route params subscription observes an empty object!

[image]

My suspicion is that the content is being sanitized by Angular after deserialization, but I haven't been able to confirm this yet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: why not just to use encodeURIComponent?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova: The encoding is valid and decodes without issue both in my code and in various other tools.  The issue ended up being scope related.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Please, include code as text, not images. No one is going to search for similar questions by using an image of their code.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a scoping/DI issue.  When I subscribe to the route params directly from a component (I had pushed this into a service), the JSON matrix params start working.